# Android, ошибка при парсе даты с сервера

Tags: java, android, json, дата, retrofit

Беру данные из сервера:

```
 Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    final UserApi service = client.create(UserApi.class);
    final Call<List<Room>> partRooms = service.getPartRooms(FROM_INT, TO_INT);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.e("samuliak", "Start execute");
                Response<List<Room>> response = partRooms.execute();
                allRooms = response.body();
                Log.e("samuliak", "exute is finished. List size > "+allRooms.size());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Модель объекта:

```
public class Room {

@SerializedName("roomID")
@Expose
private Integer roomID;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("creationDate")
@Expose
private Date creationDate;
@SerializedName("owner")
@Expose
private User owner;

public Room() {}

public Room(Integer roomID, String name, String password, Date creationDate, User owner) {
    this.roomID = roomID;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.owner = owner;
}

public Integer getRoomID() {
    return roomID;
}

public void setRoomID(Integer roomID) {
    this.roomID = roomID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(User owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

}

Ошибка:

```
07-04 07:29:09.348 9830-9956/com.project.samuliak.messenger E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-243
                                                                          Process: com.project.samuliak.messenger, PID: 9830
                                                                          com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1355263200000
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:74)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:59)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                                                                              at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
                                                                              at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
                                                                              at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116)
                                                                              at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
                                                                              at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                                                              at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
                                                                              at com.project.samuliak.messenger.fragments.tab_fragments.Rooms$1.run(Rooms.java:77)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                           Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["1355263200000']: Invalid time zone indicator '0' (at offset 0)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:274)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:72)
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:59) 
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41) 
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116) 
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216) 
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) 
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
                                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
                                                                              at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37) 
                                                                              at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25) 
                                                                              at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116) 
                                                                              at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211) 
                                                                              at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174) 
                                                                              at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89) 
                                                                              at com.project.samuliak.messenger.fragments.tab_fragments.Rooms$1.run(Rooms.java:77) 
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator '0'
```

Как решить ?

**UPDATE**

Проблема решена, но появилась новая. Стек лист ошибки :

```
07-04 07:55:31.475 19841-19962/com.project.samuliak.messenger E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-267
                                                                            Process: com.project.samuliak.messenger, PID: 19841
                                                                            com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 172 path $[0].owner.imageByteArray
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                                                                                at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
                                                                                at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116)
                                                                                at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
                                                                                at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                                                                at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
                                                                                at com.project.samuliak.messenger.fragments.tab_fragments.Rooms$1$1.run(Rooms.java:95)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 172 path $[0].owner.imageByteArray
                                                                                at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116) 
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216) 
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) 
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
                                                                                at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37) 
                                                                                at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25) 
                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116) 
                                                                                at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211) 
                                                                                at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174) 
                                                                                at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89) 
                                                                                at com.project.samuliak.messenger.fragments.tab_fragments.Rooms$1$1.run(Rooms.java:95) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**UPDATE #2**

User:

```
public class User implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("userID")
@Expose
private Integer userID;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("occupation")
@Expose
private String occupation;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private Integer age;
@SerializedName("imageByteArray")
@Expose
private byte[] imageByteArray;

public User() {}

public User(String name, String password, String occupation, Integer age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.occupation = occupation;
    this.age = age;
}

public Integer getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getOccupation() {
    return occupation;
}

public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
    this.occupation = occupation;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length);
}

public void setImage(Bitmap photo) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    imageByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
}

/////////////////// Parcelable

protected User(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    password = in.readString();
    occupation = in.readString();
    imageByteArray = in.createByteArray();
}

public static final Creator<User> CREATOR = new Creator<User>() {
    @Override
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new User(in);
    }

    @Override
    public User[] newArray(int size) {
        return new User[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(password);
    dest.writeString(occupation);
    dest.writeByteArray(imageByteArray);
}
```

}

Comment: полный класс Room покажите. по виду вы строку в массив байт загружаете.

Comment: добавил. Я просто перевожу картинку в массив байтов.

Comment: В User'е? Ну поступите аналогичным образом. Добавьте адаптер, десериализующий вашу картинку по строке в байты.

Comment: Добавил User в главный пост. В Юзере я принимаю картинку и перевожу её в байты. Не могу понять как исправить ..

Comment: обновил ответ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson не может ваш формат даты распознать, помогите ему:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter());
builder.registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, new ByteArrayAdapter());
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder.create()))
            .build();

public class DateTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Date>{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return new Date(json.getAsLong());
    }
}

public class ByteArrayAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {
    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return json.getAsString().getBytes();
    }
}
```

С массивом не уверен, лучше сделать свой класс-wrapper для byte[]...

Comment: спасибо, помогло. Но появилась новая ошибка